# Chrome wrong response encoding

Tags: node.js, google-chrome

Have nodeJs server, and react app, before today all worked perfect, now getting following response in Google Chrome while firefox works without any problem. Any idea what can be wrong?
There response should looks like common json

```
 { "first_name": "Alex"...}
```

Tried private mode, upgrading chrome, removing all extensions. Nothing help. 
On backend site I did not do any changes. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: please post your headers

Comment: More details here would be helpful: version of NodeJS, Chrome version, Firefox version, request or response headers like Content-Type, Accept, Accept-Charset

Comment: @ThomasAndolf added headers

Comment: @stealththeninja added headers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was on server side:
I compared what headers send chrome and firefox and a difference was in `accept-encoding`:

Firefox:
`"accept-encoding" = "gzip, deflate"` 
Chrome: 
`"accept-encoding"= "gzip, deflate, br"`

After remove `br` works fine.